# HMR For Production

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

My team is building a large React application. I am wanting to know if what we are trying to accomplish in regards to build and deployment are possible with Webpack.

Let’s say our team is building Google Admin. There are 4 modules/app within the admin that 4 different teams are focused on. There is then a console application that is the entry point to these 4 modules/apps. We want to be able to work on each of the modules independently and be able to deploy them independently.

How we have it setup right now is there would be 4 separate applications that are dev harnesses to build these modules. We build them and copy the distribution `.js` and `.js.map` files to the console's `./modules` folder. We would reference these modules lazily using `System.import`.

Is it possible, while the console app is built and in production, to “swap out” the `module-one.js` and `module-one.js.map` files that the console depends on without having to rebuild and redeploy the entire console app?

Goals:

1. Do not package these apps for npm. This would definitely require the console app to update and rebuild.
2. Build any module and deploy just that specific module to production without having to rebuild the console application.
3. Do not redirect to separate SPAs.

I tried my best to explain the goal. Any input would be much appreciated. I have found nothing in my search.

Answer (score 0):

webpack loads the modules into memory and watches the filesystem for changes, as long as webpack is running you shouldn't have an issue replacing any given module. However webpack will attempt to build the entire in memory bundle with each module change (as it has no way of knowing that your module is truly independent). The only thing I can thin of would be to write a shim between the console app and the modules that watches the files (like webpack) but only replaces the in memory version of the local file that was changed. Reading this I'm not even sure if it makes sense to me...